# ObjectifyService.init() method is undefined

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, objectify

I am attempting to use `Objectify` in an App Engine project in Eclipse with the Cloud Tools SDK. The setup section of Objectify's GitHub wiki says:

> Call `ObjectifyService.init()` in the bootstrap of your application; a
>   servlet context listener is ideal.

Every tutorial or question I've found says the same thing, but Eclipse is telling me that the `ObjectifyService.init()` method doesn't exist. The code below comes from the Objectify GitHub wiki.

```
public class Bootstrapper implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ObjectifyService.init();    //"The method init() is undefined for the type ObjectifyService"
        ObjectifyService.register(MyClass.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Is this call no longer needed? Are all of the tutorials, even what looks like the official documentation, out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost certainly included the wrong version of Objectify on your classpath. Make sure there is only the v6 version present.

Comment: That is what I thought at first, but I haven't manually included it anywhere. I just checked a box when I created the project with the Cloud Tools SDK plugin. I commented out the line it is complaining about and everything seems to work.

Comment: I can only tell you this: Objectify v5 doesn't have an init() method. v6 does, and requires you to call it. There's nothing wrong with using v5 if you're in App Engine Standard, but you should know which one you're using :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I started a new project without choosing the objectify option and added it myself. Everything is working as expected now.